# Is there a way to initialize all items in a 2d array with inputted dimensions without looping in C++?

Tags: c++, arrays, initialization

Is there a way to initialize all items in a 2d array with console-inputted dimensions to a specified item without looping in C++?
For example, say I have two integers, x and y, and a 2d array called grid:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    int x, y;
    std::cout << "Enter the dimensions of the array separated by a space: ";
    std::cin >> x >> y;
    bool grid [x][y] {/*all false*/};
    // other code
    return 0;
}
```

Is there any way to initialize every item in `grid` in the format above? I tried:

```cpp
    bool grid [x][y] {false};
```

but that just set the first item to false.

Comment: Do note that variable lenght arrays [are not part of C++ standard](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1887097/6865932) though some compilers allow its use.

Comment: "but that just set the first item to false." --> are you sure?  I'd expect that do to initialize the first to `false` and all  elements to initialize to their default values.

Comment: @chuxReinstateMonica Yes, when I used that syntax and printed the values of the array there were all kinds of numbers besides 0. When I changed the values using a ```for``` loop, every item was 0 as I expected, so the code I wrote above doesn't work.

Comment: @anastaciu what you say seems to be what's causing the problem. With hardcoded dimensions, the above code works. I'll change that. Thanks!

Comment: @NotMyAccount If you make the dimensions hardcoded you need to make `grid` big enough to hold the biggest `x` and the biggest `y` the user is allowed to specify, even if the user only wants a `1 x 1` grid. That's not good. When the dimensions are not known at compile time, use a `std::vector`.

Comment: @tedlyngmo Okay, thanks for the tip! However, for my purposes, hardcoding the array size is fine because this is for a previous contest problem I'm doing for practice and the inputs are given through the console, and there are limits to how big the dimensions will be. I'll use vectors if I run into a similar situation in the future, though. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature. Moreover even in C where vaeiable length arrays are included in the Standard nevertheless you may not initialize them in declaration.

In C++ you should use the standard class template `std::vector`.

For example

```
int x, y;
std::cout << "Enter the dimensions of the array separated by a space: ";
std::cin >> x >> y;
std::vector<std::vector<bool>> grid( x, std::vector<bool>( y ) );
```

The last statement declares a vector of vector all elements of which will be set to false.

Comment: However, there are some drawbacks to this approach: the 2-D array is not contiguous in memory, there are multiple separate memory allocations, and the syntax for declaring the 2-D vector is a little messy. I'd be tempted to use a single std::vector and manually index into it - perhaps all wrapped in a class to hide the details.

Comment: @EricBackus There is no any drawback. It is possible to speak about drawbacks only in the context of a concrete application.  So using a single vector with calculating indices as for a vector of vectors can be very error prone and be a big drawback.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `memset`. You can read more about it [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/memset-in-cpp/)

What it does is it sets the block of memory that you specify to what you pass.

Answer (score 0):

`bool grid [x][y]` when `x` and `y` are not `constexpr` makes `grid` a VLA (Variable Length Array). VLA:s do not exist in standard C++ and are only available as an extension in some compilers. I suggest that you do not use them. Side note: You usually want to swap `x` and `y` since arrays are stored in row major order in memory and access to elements if you access them row-by-row is likely to be faster because of how caches work.

The idiomatic way is to use a [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() {
    size_t x, y; // a suiteable unsigned type

    std::cout << "Enter the dimensions of the array separated by a space: ";
    std::cin >> x >> y;

    // create a 2D vector, all initialized to "false"
    std::vector<std::vector<bool>> grid(y, std::vector<bool>(x, false));  

    for(size_t yval = 0; yval < grid.size(); ++yval) {
        for(size_t xval = 0; xval < grid[yval].size(); ++xval) {
            std::cout << grid[yval][xval];
        }
        std::cout << '\n';
    }  
}
```

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can initialize using memset.

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    int row=5;
    int col=6;
    int mat[row][col];
    memset(mat, 0, sizeof(mat[0][0]) * row * col);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

- If you really want the values to be `false`, you can use `bool grid[x][y] = {};`. This works because the braces give a list of initial values, and when this is done then all remaining values in the array are zero initialized, which will give a value of false. Note: this is valid C++, but C does not allow an empty initialization list, so for plain C you would need `bool grid[x][y] = {false};`.
- As bhristov mentions above, you can use `memset`. But this is not good c++ style in my opinion.
- You can use std::fill or std::fill_n, because the 2-D array is a contiguous set of values of length `x * y`. This has the advantage of allowing you to specify other values than just `false`.

Comment: This works. However, if what you said in the first point is true, then when I set the first item to ```false``` with ```{false}```, why didn't the rest of the values initialize to false as well?

Comment: Actually I think your original code should have worked. Note that my answer used an `=` sign, while your original code did not, but it don't think it should have made any difference. Is it possible that the variable-length arrays have different behavior?

Comment: Variable length arrays are not valid C++. They are provided by a non-standard compiler extension, so it is entirely possible for them to behave differently.

Comment: @EricBackus when incorporating your answer into my code I didn't use "=" and it still worked.

Comment: @BessieTheCow That seems to be true. When I try my malfunctioning code with hardcoded dimensions, it works.